# Changing currency/home country for Google Checkout Account for Apps sold on Google Play

Tags: android, android-pay, google-checkout

I am a developer selling Android apps through Google Play and I live in Canada.  Currently Google pays me out in Canadian Dollars into my Canadian bank account.  What governs the currency I receive my payments in? Is it my home country?  Is it possible to change the currency to USD if I move to USA or can I have the money deposited into a US Dollar account in Canada in US Dollars?
Also is it possible to pay out to more than 1 bank account in different percentages?

Answer (score 3):

Google Play merchant payments are in one currency only.
You will only be paid in the currency of your home country, in this case Canada.

You cannot select the payment currency or receive payment in a currency that does not match the currency of your domestic bank account.

More information in this Help Center article:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1169947?hl=en&ref_topic=15867

Comment: What happens if I move to USA and open a us bank account?  Google will still try to pay me in Canadian dollars ?

Comment: Got this exact problem right now. Moved from Japan to Switzerland and can't find a way to change my country and bank account. So all that is left to me is to transfer the money from japan to switzerland every time.. Really annoying.

Comment: also having this issue..any solutions maybe?

Comment: @PatrickBoos but, you can do that thing another way. 1. Create a new account with your swiss address. 2. Transfer your apps one-by-one to another account, as per this.https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en

Comment: @kmonsoor yes that is correct. That is what I actually ended up doing :( It is rather annoying.

Comment: @kmonsoor then pay another $25 to Google for creating a new account... :(

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: If you are going to open a bank account in US, try opening a new developer account with the new US credit card, fill in all the info as required for the US account. Then transfer your apps to your new account.
How to transfer: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

Comment: What will happen to my pending current earnings that point to the old bank account?

Comment: Your earnings in current account will be paid to your current bank account. Obviously ) Just don't close your bank account until you get all the earnings.

Comment: Do you mean that the current outstanding balance on Google Play will be paid to the old bank account? (I assume "current bank account" = the old one)